# Android Smack Client goes offline

Tags: java, android, openfire

I am having requirement cross platform communication [ chat ].

So I have used XMPP Protocol but some times my Smack Android client goes automatically offline

Server Details :

Operating system : Linux

XMPP Server : Openfire 3.7.1

Android side Smack API for communication [ chat ]

And on server side I have configured all the things like never disconnects client in "Idle Connections Policy "

Comment: Is there any errors in the logcat ?

Comment: I wonder how this question could get 5 upvotes: It is basically just a "does not work" with some component descriptions query. There are **no** logs provided and no description what has been tried to solve this. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Now in latest 4.1.0 we have connection configuration.
more debug logs with more details.

Try the following.

```
// Create a connection
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration connConfig = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setServiceName(SERVICE)
            .setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
            .setDebuggerEnabled(true).build();

XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try enabling SMACK log on the client side maybe you see something

```
XmppConnectionFactory.setDebug(true)
```